# Significato di "buttarla sul fisico" e altre espressioni con "buttarla"

Tags: word-usage, meaning, colloquial

Nel romanzo *Ferito a morte*, di Raffaele La Capria, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Pettinandosi davanti allo specchio Ninì gonfia il torace, fa un inchino alla ragazza che sta arrivando con Cocò – una specie di prova generale – ma decide che no, **buttarla sul fisico** è volgare, *savoir faire* ci vuole! Ripete l’inchino a torace sgonfio, sobrio, all’inglese, così va meglio, e s’avvia a fare pipì.

Per si fosse di aiuto, si tratta di un romanzo ambientato a Napoli.

Potreste spiegarmi cosa vuol dire "buttarla sul fisico" in questo brano?

Ho letto tutte le accezioni della [voce "buttare" sul vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/buttare), ma non riesco a vedere a quale possa corrispondere l'uso che se ne fa nel testo. Le definizioni che ho trovato su altri dizionari sono simili.

Ricercando "buttarla sul", "buttarla sullo", "buttarla sulla" su Google Libri ne appaiono parecchie occorrenze che a volte si riferiscono chiaramente a "buttare" in senso fisico (per esempio, "buttarla sul letto"), ma altre volte hanno un senso figurato che non so se sia lo stesso di quello adoperato da La Capria in questo passaggio. Se fosse così, potreste fare qualche esempio di come si usa questa espressione?

Comment: È un’espressione  informale dove “buttarla” , in questo caso significa “mettere la questione” sull’aspetto fisico, porre l’accento sulla fisicità (di Nini). Molto usata l’espressione romana “buttarla in cacciara”.

Comment: Cosa significa "buttarla in cacciara", @Hachi?

Comment: Buttarla in caciara, è una tipica espressione romana, che vuole significare, più o meno, far perdere, in una questione, il filo, o i punti cruciali. Sviare, glissare, cambiare argomento; snaturare o appannare, quelli che sono gli elementi fondamentali, in un discorso. http://cesarimarco.blogspot.com/2015/06/buttarla-in-caciara.html

Comment: Il senso di buttare in “buttarla” è indirizzare l’attenzione in una certa direzione. “Buttarla sul ridere” ad esempio, per sdrammatizzare una situazione.

Comment: @Hachi:  Cioè, "buttarla sul ridere" significherebbe concentrarsi sull'aspetto comico di una situazione per cercare di finire ridendo?

Comment: No, significa “indirizzare” la conversazione o la discussione  su aspetti più leggeri, spesso cambiando discorso.

Comment: Qui trovi alcuni esempi: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22buttarla%20sul%20ridere%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_it

Comment: Nel link alla Treccani riportato, il significato è quello figurato riportato al punto 5: "Tendere, volgersi a qualche cosa", nel senso che indica @Hachi nel suo primo commento, di "portare in una certa direzione". Nel caso in questione mi pare di capire che il personaggio sta cercando di sedurre una ragazza; "buttarla sul fisico" significa cercare di sedurla col proprio aspetto fisico: il personaggio "gonfia il torace" e "fa un inchino" (insomma, si mette in mostra, si pavoneggia), ma poi decide che la cosa è "volgare" e cerca un approccio più sottile.

Comment: Ah, OK, @Riccardo. Veramente quando ho letto gli esempi che appaiono al punto 5 del vocabolario Treccani  ("un colore che butta al rosso" e "il tempo s’è buttato a buono, a neve, a pioggia"), non ho pensato che potessero avere a che vedere con questa espressione. Penso che il ragazzo stia facendo prove davanti allo specchio di quello che cercarà di fare dopo con questa ragazza.

Comment: @Charo hai ragione

Comment: Credo che "buttarla sul ridere" e simili siano molto più comuni (e sensati) di "colore che butta al rosso" e "il tempo si butta al buono".

Comment: Più che "colore che butta al rosso"  in italiano direi più frequentemente "colore che ***volge*** al rosso"  e "il tempo ***volge*** al buono"; il verbo voltare mi sembra più adatto...

Answer (score 4):

Nel [link alla Treccani riportato](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/buttare), il significato è quello figurato riportato al punto 5:

> Tendere, volgersi a qualche cosa (in senso fig.)

nel senso che indica @Hachi nel suo primo commento, di *"portare in una certa direzione"*.

Nel caso in questione il personaggio è davanti allo specchio e sta facendo una specie di "prova generale" per cercare di sedurre una ragazza; "*buttarla sul fisico*" significa cercare di sedurla col proprio aspetto fisico, "*spinge*" (altra espressione usata in questo senso) sul proprio aspetto fisico: il personaggio "gonfia il torace" e "fa un inchino" (insomma, si mette in mostra, si pavoneggia), ma poi decide che la cosa è "volgare" e che cercherà un approccio più sottile.